# Find SQL parameters passed with C# without SQL Server Profiler

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am binding a telerik grid with the `SqlDataSource` of type stored proc. I also have some parameters added in the `SqlDataSource`.

Now I would like to know what are the final values that were being passed to the stored procedure on the server. I don't have the permissions to use SQL Server profiler.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlSource" runat="server" SelectCommand="dbo.sp_abc" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="pUserID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="pMasterUserID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="pDBID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="pIncludeHistoric" Type="Boolean" DefaultValue="False" 
            ControlID="chkCurrentOnly" PropertyName="Checked" />        
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Is there any way best way to find the values sent to the database at the application server side?

Comment: What do you mean find the values..? if you are using `Parameters.AddWithValue(@param, paramvalue);` you should know the value of the parameter being passed in .. unless I am not understanding your question here.. do you have code example you are using..?

Comment: Hi, do you mean you have a custom black box SqlDataSource that computes private parameters before sending them to the stored procedure ?

Comment: As you can see, code in comments is impossible to read.  I have moved your code to the question.

Comment: I guess you could subscribe to the Selecting event of your sqlDataSource to check the parameters before they are being sent to the DB server

Answer (score 0):

you should bind your data to your grid manually and not use a SQLDataSource. 
This would allow you to "see" the values of the parameters sent to the grid.

Comment: Problem is I am not getting the values back from the database even though the right parameters are passed.

Comment: @Krishna: Is it not evident from the output of the Telerik grid?

Answer (score 0):

The only way i see this possible is to run your application on a local mssql server, or any other mssql server where you do have permission. this will allow you you to profile.

You can copy the database with mssms without having to have root privileges by using the `the SQL Management Object method`, this might take some time if your database is very large.

Look at this link for more info on how to copy a database across servers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188664.aspx#Copy_Move

Answer (score 0):

Check out [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/)

It will show you how long certain methods took to execute, which SQL code was run and the parameters/values that was passed.  I've only used this with MVC but this should work with WebForms too.